# Variable length list with # and [[i]] as elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to create a list that as an input receives the number $N$ of elements that it will contain and that returns:

```
{{_,_,#[[1]]},{_,_,#[[2]]},{_,_,#[[3]]},...{_,_,#[[N]]}}
```

I've tried using `Hold` and `Release` but haven't come up with a solution.

Comment: How about `ToExpression[Table [StringJoin["{_,_,#[[",ToString[k],"]]}"],{k,1,n}]]` ? You might want to add an `&` at the end of your list.

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  Are you trying to generate some code?  For what end?

Comment: I am trying to generate this list to use it in a pattern match operation: Position[ToExpression /@ 
    indParList, {{_, _, #[[1]]}, {_, _, #[[2]]}}] & /@ tuples   in which the tuples list may vary in length and therefore the pattern match array should adapt to this variation

Comment: This is a bad way of doing it. Why not just transpose your data and then use the last element? It will automatically work for all values of `n`.

Comment: @rm-rf Agree, but perhaps `n != Lenght@tuples[[_]]`. It can be fixed easily though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `Thread[{_, _, #}]` applied to each tuple thus:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[RandomInteger[1, {RandomInteger[{2, 4}], 3}], {100}];
tuples = Table[RandomInteger[1, RandomInteger[{2, 4}]], {5}];
```

Application:

```
pos = Position[data, Thread[{_, _, #}]] & /@ tuples
(* {{{38}, {82}}, {{33}, {43}, {47}, {94}}, {{58}}, {{37}, {85}, {88}}, {}} *)
```

Check:

```
Grid[
 MapThread[{Map[Last, Extract[data, #1], {2}], #2} &, {pos, tuples}],
 Alignment -> Left]
(* {{1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}                   {1, 1, 0, 0}
   {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}   {1, 1, 1}
   {{0, 0, 1, 0}}                                 {0, 0, 1, 0}
   {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}              {1, 0, 0}
   {}                                             {0, 0, 1, 1}}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could also consider:

```
(* Michael's data *)
SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[RandomInteger[1, {RandomInteger[{2, 4}], 3}], {100}];
tuples = Table[RandomInteger[1, RandomInteger[{2, 4}]], {5}];
```

Then:

```
Position[Last /@ Transpose /@ data, Alternatives @@ tuples]
(*
==> {{33}, {37}, {38}, {43}, {47}, {58}, {82}, {85}, {88}, {94}}
*)
```

or

```
Position[Last /@ Transpose /@ data, #] & /@ tuples
(*
==> {{{38}, {82}}, {{33}, {43}, {47}, {94}}, {{58}}, {{37}, {85}, {88}}, {}}
*)
```

or Simon's (slickest)

```
Position[data[[All, All, -1]], #] & /@ tuples
```

Comment: I was waiting for rm-rf or you to post this.  The `Alternatives` one will probably bog down on long lists of `tuples`.  But the second one should be faster than mine.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've seen his comment a few hours ago, but thought he wasn't going to post it. Anyway this is the first thing I would think of for this problem, and surely not pattern matching

Comment: Could also use `data[[All, All, -1]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Nice one. Going to add it